# Div content not refreshing in IE (screen refresh)

Tags: html, internet-explorer

my application working well in all browsers except IE.
In my application I have a div popup form which contains some fields. In the text box it i pressed any key it was not displaying. If i move the mouse then the entered texts are displaying actual thing is screen not refreshed
How to solve this.

mycode:

```
<form>
    //this is popup form
    <div>
        <form>
            <input type="text"/>
            <!-- if i type in the text box in IE it is not displaying but in some pc only -->
        </form>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Could you give some more information? Perhaps paste some code samples of the parts that are not working?

Comment: It looks like you tried to paste a sample but it isn't visible.

Comment: jree, you can highlight the code and press ctrl+k, or the `code sample` button, to display properly your code samples.

Comment: FYI, form elements shouldn't be nested within other form elements.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you want to have a popup, containing a form. The code you pasted is just html; it does not have any of this interactivity.

Let's start with your code. It has a form with a form inside it. The form tag is used to specify the start of a web form. You can specify several thing in this tag:

- action: Where will the form be posted to? e.g. send the form to http://www.example.com/processform/
- method: Will the form be submitted using the GET or POST method?

Having a second form tag inside it doesn't make sense: your browser will not know where to post the form to. Most browsers will choose to use one of the two tags, but they might choose the wrong one or ignore the form tags entirely.

If you want to have a form in a popup, use an approach like following html code:

```
<p><span id="clickablelink">Open the form</span></p>
<div class="dialog" style="display: none;">
  <form action="/process/" method="post">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit this form" />
  </form>
</div>
```

This code part should be inside the  part of your html document.

You cannot open a dialog in the same page, unless you use JavaScript, jQuery or another framework to display this form. An example of this using jQuery UI:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/themename/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
      });
      $("#clickablelink").click(function(){
        $(".dialog").dialog("open");
      });
    });
</script>
```

This code block should be inside the  part of your html document.

This is just a basic example. It might not be exactly what you are looking for. It is meant to show you in what directions you can look for your specific solution. I would suggest putting more details in your question:

- For what purpose are you using this website?
- What will this form be used for?
- Why are you displaying a form inside a dialog?

Answering these questions and specifying your problem help you understand what you are trying to achieve and help us to answer your question properly.

You can read more about forms and javascript dialogs at the following links:

- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp
- http://mdrisser.r1designs.net/blog/?p=3

And for information about the jQuery framework:

- http://www.jquery.com
- http://ui.jquery.com